Error when attempting to run equal rates ancestral character estimation
I'm trying to run an ancestral character estimation assuming equal rates using the "ape" package. I've read my phylogeny in as a NEXUS file and my discrete traits in a list.
However, when I try to carry out the "ace" command, I get the following error:
> equalrates_model = lapply (var.list, function (x) ace (x, tree,
+                                                        type = "discrete",
+                                                        model = "ER"))
Error in names(obj$ace) <- phy$node.label : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Here is the structure of my tree:
> str (tree)
List of 6
 $ edge       : int [1:92, 1:2] 48 49 50 51 51 50 52 52 53 53 ...
 $ edge.length: num [1:92] 0.0137 0.0146 0.0271 0.0389 0.0674 ...
 $ Nnode      : int 46
 $ node.label : int [1:46] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ root.edge  : num 0
 $ tip.label  : chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
 - attr(*, "order")= chr "cladewise"

and here is the structure of my list of traits:
> str(var.list)
List of 12
 $ Species    : Named chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Hemiptera  : Named int [1:47] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Diptera    : Named int [1:47] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Hymenoptera: Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Lepidoptera: Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Orthoptera : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Coleoptera : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Trichoptera: Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Araneae    : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Psocodea   : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Blattodea  : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...
 $ Mantodea   : Named int [1:47] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "Ectemnius_sonorensis" "Dasyproctus_spec" "Lindenius_panzeri2" "Crossocerus_quadrimaculatus" ...

Any help in solving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Could you share a minimum reproducible example so that we can reproduce and check the bug please? Although from the bug text and the data information you've put, you might bypass the bug by removing the node labels from you tree tree$node.label <- NULL
